# Rename touch up event in iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode

I am writing my first iOS application and in it, I have created a form and created a submit button touch up event. Now I want to rename the function associated with the event. How can I do that?

Just renaming the function in ViewControllers doesn't help because the link on Storyboard still shows the old name.

Comment: Rename the function(i assume its an IBAction).Then in storyboard disconnect the connection and connect it again

Comment: How to refactor? Sorry, I am really new to iOS development and am using XCode for first time.

Comment: yes @Anil that works. But is there a way to rename directly?

Comment: @marrock, check my answer about refactoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to refactor it, that usually renames it everywhere but inside a `@selector(...)`, there you have to rename it manually case by case – otherwise your app may crashes after you call an undefined selector on an instance.

right click on the name, then:

[image]